# How to create a HTML5 time input using the CakePHP form helper?

Tags: html, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I faced cakephp time format problem. I am tired, this problem. When i try 'type' => 'time' then it change like my first screen short. But i want to need like second screen short.

```
echo $this->Form->input('callback_time', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'callentry_time_formate readonly','data-live-search' => 'true','type' => 'time', 'value' => (!empty($this->request->data['CallEntry']['callback_time'])) ? $this->request->data['CallEntry']['callback_time'] : $callback_time));
```

Screen Short: 1
[image]

I want to need like under this picture. How can i solved it?
Screen Short: 2
[image]

Screen Short: 3
when i go inspect element in browser and change type='time' then it work well like my Screen Short: 3 
if i change cakephp helper input 'type' => 'time' then it look like screen short: 1. My required Screen Short:3. But it's working only inspect element 
[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear , if you put type ="time" , then If it's working fine then what's your problem ?

Comment: when i am try type = 'time' then it look my first image but i want to need like second image

Comment: if i use type = 'time' in cakephp input then it broken like my first screen but my required like second screen. second screen make in inspect element

Comment: Do u want to see it like as text field ? or like as time picker ?

Comment: like a time picker

Comment: i already get it but need a pattern like html time format --:-- --

Comment: Maybe it is not a problem in your case, but remember that using a HTML5 `time` input won't render the same in every browsers. Firefox and IE just show a simple `text` input for instance.

Answer (score 4):

The `type` option of `FormHelper::input()` doesn't necessarily translate directly to the HTML `type` attribute, but rather to the according `FormHelper` widget/element, and in case of `time`, this is multiple inputs for the individual time value components.

### Use `FormHelper::text()`

If you need a single `<input>` element with the `type` attribute set, then you'll have to create the element directly via `FormHelper::text()`, where `type` will map to the HTML attribute, ie

```
$this->Form->text('callback_time', array(
    'type' => 'time',
    // ...
));
```

Of course you'll loose the magic that `FormHelper::input()` provides, ie error messages, wrappers, etc, you'll have to handle that on your own then.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > FormHelper > Creating form elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#automagic-form-elements)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > FormHelper > Creating form elements > Options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > FormHelper > Displaying and checking errors](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#displaying-and-checking-errors)**

### Use your own (extended) form helper

Another option would be to create your own, extend `FormHelper`, and either implement your own type, or override `FormHelper::_getInput()` or `FormHelper::dateTime()`, to make the built-in `time` type use the elements that you need. Here's an example doing the former:

**app/View/Helper/MyFormHelper.php**

```
App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper');

class MyFormHelper extends FormHelper
{
    public function customTime($fieldName, $options = array())
    {
        $options =
            $this->_initInputField($fieldName, $options) + array('type' => 'time');

        return $this->Html->useTag(
            'input',
            $options['name'],
            array_diff_key($options, array('name' => null))
        );
    }
}
```

That's basically the same as above (see `FormHelper::__call()`, which is being invoked for `FormHelper::text()`), ie it creates a simple `<input>` element with the `type` attribute set, but keeps the magic that `FormHelper::input()` provides.

**controller**

```
public $helpers = array(
    'MyForm',
    // ...
);
```

**.ctp view template**

```
$this->MyForm->input('callback_time', array(
    'type' => 'customTime',
    // ...
));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Creating Helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Creating Helpers > Using your Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-your-helper)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery-timepicker to create a time picker.

http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: i used already but i want to need html input type format  when i used 'type' => 'time' then it broken like my first screen short but my required like this    http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_time

Comment: i used that but it work like my first screen short but need like second screen short